# How can I disable the popup success message when the form is required to fill?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am planning to display a Success message when clicked on the Submit button.
However, I would like to disable or hide the Success message whenever the form is required to fill.
So how can I do it by changing the code in script?
Please help me, I really appreciate your support!

This is my code:

```html
<div class="contact-wrapper">
  <main class="flex-container">
    <section class="main-content">
      <form class="contact-form" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
        <input type="text" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Name" id="name" required/>
        <input type="email" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Email" id="email" required/>
        <input type="text" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Title">
        <textarea class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Type your message..."></textarea>
        <button>Send</button>

        <div class="alert">
          <span class="message">Success: You Message Sent Successfully!</span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </section>

<script>
  function validateForm() {
    var name =  document.getElementById('name').value;
    var name =  document.getElementById('email').value;
  }

  $('button').click(function(){
    $('.alert').addClass("show");
    $('.alert').addClass("showAlert");
    $('.alert').removeClass("hide");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.alert').addClass("hide");
      $('.alert').removeClass("show");
    },3000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please include any other dependencies you are using within the project (css libraries, js libraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider hiding the message initially and display it only on successful submission

```
<div class="alert hide">
     <span class="message">Success: You Message Sent Successfully!</span>
</div>
```

you should show the alert only if the form validation returns true.

```
function validateForm() {
    var name =  document.getElementById('name').value;
    var email =  document.getElementById('email').value;
    if(name == '' || name == null || email == '' || email == null){
       alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
       return false;
      }
    return true;
  }
```

```
$('button').click(function(){
     if(validateForm()){
       // your code for submission
       // after successful submission display the alert message
       $('.alert').removeClass("hide");
       $('.alert').addClass("show");
       $('.alert').addClass("showAlert");    
     }
    
  });
```

I would suggest you to follow the standard format for `form validation` and `form submission`. [link here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm)